# C# to post data to ASP .Net application

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

All I want is to send xml data from C# desktop application to ASP.Net webpage.
My C# code look like this.

```
public string SendRequest()
{   string data = "<?xml version="1.0"?><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>";
    string _result;
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:62511/Default");
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Close();

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
    _result = streamRead.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    streamRead.Close();
    streamResponse.Close();
    response.Close();
    return _result;
}
```

My ASP .Net Code looks like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();

        labelsam.Text = xml;
    }
    ....
}
```

labelsam is a label on web page.But I get nothin in labelsam.Is there anyway to check whether the data is received.Also whats wrong with code?

Comment: What response/s do you get back? Also, you should look at making use of `IDisposable`. Make use of `using`.

Comment: how to check the response?

Comment: Erm, debug it? Dump it out to the console, a windows form? Whatever's your preference really.

Comment: Thanks.I see the data on console but not on webpage.Can you please tell me whats the problem?

Comment: It's pretty clear that you're a beginner to C# and programming in general. I suggest that you start by doing some basic tutorials first before tackling something like this. When you're done, you'll have the tools and the knowhow to figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify content length for post method.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength=data.Length; //ugly, but at least so
var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(data);
writer.Close();
```